# ssc.sparkContext.parallelize in foreachPartition raise Task not serializable Exception

Tags: scala, serialization, spark-streaming

In foreachPartition i want to translate a list of String to an rdd, i use ssc.sparkContext.parallelize, and the ssc is an object of StreamingContext. The code is like this:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
...
words.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords => {
  var sourcelist = List[String]()
  partitionOfRecords.foreach(x=>{sourcelist=sourcelist.+:("source"+x)})
  if(sourcelist.length > 0 ){
    sourcelist.foreach { x => println(x) }
  }else{
    println("aa---------------------none")
  }
  // change the sourcelist to a RDD an convert it to a Dstream
  val ssd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(sourcelist)
  val resultInputStream = ssc.queueStream(scala.collection.mutable.Queue(ssd))
  val results  = resultInputStream.map(x=>x)
  results.print()
}})
```

But, the code raise SparkException: Task not serializable. I really don't known how to do with this.Appreciate your help, Please!

Comment: This error means, you are trying to access Non-Serializable class inside rdd transformations.

Comment: i guess you are trying to get sparkContext from the ssc, which is not serializable class. you can try to get the sparkContext from RDD itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to translate a string list to a RDD, how to do with it? Just like the List object sourcelist in the question, how to make it a RDD object?

Comment: you need to change the logic what you written inside `words.foreachRDD`, basically you are doing two different things, one is preparing `sourceList` and then you are using that list to do something. The second part you are actually doing nothing, you are returning the list as RDD.

Comment: what do you want to do with `sourceList`?

Comment: write a string list  to kafka

Comment: Actually what you are doing is, from `words.foreachRDD(rdd=> {}` this you are actually creating the same rdd again, inside this foreachRDD, you are building the rdd from the same rdd, nothing else.. now tell me, what do you want to do with `words` DStream?

Comment: firstly, i read data from kafka, and  i use rdd.foreachPartition to deal with data on each distributed machine, after processed these data, i generated a list of string, then i want write the list back to the kafka, also i want write these data to hdfs.